# SP2016 Powershell: Error Updating OwnerAlias - InvalidData

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to update a site collection's owner and secondary with PowerShell.  Currently, they're blank and CA fails.  I enter the following in PowerShell:

```
Get-SPSite "http://company/division/site" | %{Set-SPSite $_ -OwnerAlias "spadmin" -SecondaryOwnerAlias "altspadmin"}
```

The following error is returned:

> Set-SPSite :    At line:11 char:46
>   + Get-SPSite "http://company/division/site" | %{Set-SPSite $_ -OwnerAlias "spadmin ...
>   +                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletSetSite:SPCmdletSetSite) [Set-SPSite],
>   SPException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletSetSite

(The highlight is under the Set-SPSite command.)  The names are valid.
 Even the domain\name fails.

Note: I don't know if this has something to do with the error, but I notice that the content db is missing the SPDataAccess and SPReadOnly.  Do you know how to get these roles installed?

Comment: **Note:** <User> should be added with this format <domain>\<username>. not as you did "spadmin" so it should be "domain\spadmin"

Comment: ???  Yes.  I did that. (Per my explanation.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't note that! but in error message you have tried this cmdlet without domain !! `Get-SPSite "http://company/division/site" | %{Set-SPSite $_ -OwnerAlias "spadmin"`  so Could you please try this command `Set-SPSite -Identity "<SiteCollection>" -SecondaryOwnerAlias "<domain>\<username>"` and check if you face the same issue or not!

Comment: Can you try it as `i:0#.w|Domain\Username` ?

Comment: M.Qassas: I tried it.  Same error.

Comment: Gautam: I tried the claims format.  Same error.  I get the feeling that I'm dealing with a corrupted database.  The DB originally had DBCC errors.  Those have since been resolved, but I'm guessing that there's some SharePoint pointers left unresolved.  Is there a good powershell "test" for the integrity of a site collection?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that you have set the **correct Site Collection URL** at `Get-SPSite "<SiteCollection>"`

  - I tried this on my side and get the same error but you looks like not copy the full error message

[image]

So run first `Get-SPSite` to can get the Site Collection list, then add the correct site collection URL in your Cmdlet

- Make sure that the **Owner Alias user** is formatted as `<domain>\<username>`

**Change site collection administrator CMDLET**

```
Set-SPSite -Identity "<SiteCollection>" -SecondaryOwnerAlias "<User>"
```

**Note:** **`<User>`** is the name of the user whom you want to add in the format `<domain>\<username>`.

For more details check [Change site collection administrators in SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631156(v=office.16).aspx)

Comment: Site collection URL is correct.  Your error message looks like mine, but the underscore is on the Set-SPSite command.  InvalidData is what I'm trying to resolve.  I tried the Set-SPSite command as you have above with domain\user and claims format, but still get InvalidData.  Any way to check the validity of a site collection with powershell?